# OpenAPI 3: Missing property "$ref"

Tags: visual-studio-code, openapi

I'm writing an API document using OpenAPI 3 in VSCode with the extension ***OpenAPI (Swagger) Editor v4.9.1***. It works pretty well until today - suddenly my document is filled with errors on "properties" within all schema declarations. The error goes:

```
Missing property "$ref". yaml-schema: Validation schema for OpenAPI Specification 3.0.X.
```

[image: error message]
Obviously, this error makes no sense at all, since **$ref is never a required field in any place** according to OpenAPI Specification.
Besides, I could still preview this document with swagger's default renderer, or generate code using its CodeGen toolchain, which indicates that this document has no actual error.
So what's happening? Is it a bug in the OpenAPI language server?

Comment: Looks like it is an issue: https://github.com/42Crunch/vscode-openapi/issues/163

Comment: Looks like they have fixed the YAML extension today - make sure you have 1.5.1 installed.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yeah, it's fixed today, I've noticed that, too.

Answer (score 3):

I have started to face the same problem today and updating your openapi version might be an interim solution.

`openapi: "3.1.0"`

Comment: This fixed the reported error, but also caused the extensions helper panes on the left of vscode to disappear - now it says "No OpenAPI file detected." Weird. I see - a known issue but the developer is blocked waiting for an update from vscode. https://github.com/42Crunch/vscode-openapi/issues/184

Answer (score 0):

You must specify schema for the parameter.
Ex:

```
parameters:
        - in: header
          name: X-Request-ID
          schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid
          required: true
```

more details https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/